# Get particular index from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm having an array:
var myArray = `["","dfg","erte","","asd"]`

How can I get the index of those elements which doesn't have `""`..?

I have this code:

```
for i in myArray {
                                                                    
  let index = myArray.firstIndex(where: {$0 == i})

}
```

This gives me the index of all elements. But I want the index of those elements which doesn't have `""`

Comment: The code you posted does not make sense. It loops through EVERY element in the array, and then on each pass, you create a local variable `index`, which you then discard on the next pass through the loop. What is your desired output. You say 'I want the index of those elements which [don't contain] "".' Does that mean you want to create an array containing the indexes of every array element that is not empty?

Comment: Plus, the loop will always either match the current element of the array or, if the same value appears more than once, it will return in the index of the first occurrence of any duplicate value.

Comment: `which doesn't have ""` You mean the string that aren't empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option is using `filter`

```
let range = myArray.indices.filter { !myArray[$0].isEmpty }
```

To access the array using `range` you can then do

```
for index in range {
    print(myArray[index])
}
```

---

Of course if the end goal is to get an array of all non-empty values then you can filter on the array directly

```
let notEmpty = myArray.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

Comment: actually @Joakim Danielson, I wanted a single index like so..`for i in myArray { let range = ...
let id = self.myIDArray[range!]
 }`

Comment: @user14822019 No, you want the indices of the elements that are not empty. That's what it says in your question. And if you want them one by one then loop over `range`

Comment: @user14822019, what do you mean you want a single index? Explain in words which index you want? The index of the first non-empty element?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to create an array of the indexes of all non-empty elements in your string array, you can do that using `enumerated()` and compactMap:

```
var myArray = ["","dfg","erte","","asd"]

let indexes = myArray.enumerated().compactMap { (index, value) in
    value.isEmpty ? nil : index
}

print(indexes)
```

That outputs:

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

If, instead, you want the index of the first non-empty element, you could use code like this:

```
if let firstNonEmptyIndex = myArray.firstIndex(where: {!$0.isEmpty}) {
    print("The entry at index \(firstNonEmptyIndex) is empty")
} else {
    print("No entries in the array are empty.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get index with offset value in here:

```
var str = ["","123","345","","789"]

for i in str.enumerated(){
    if i.element != "" {
        print(i.offset)
    }
}
```

Comment: actually my entire array is a string array..please see edited question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compactMap`  it remove nil value too(if array has)

```
var myArrayIndex = myArray.enumerated().compactMap { (index, data) -> Int? in
    if !data.isEmpty {
        return index
    }
    return nil
}
print(myArrayIndex)
```

Sort way:

```
var myArrayIndex = myArray.enumerated().compactMap{!$0.element.isEmpty ? $0.offset : nil}
print(myArrayIndex)
```